# PyCharm3, how to get rid of "cannot resolve directory" messages?

Tags: django, pycharm

I am using PyCharm3 for developing and I get "Cannot Resolve Directory" errors in places like these:

`<link href="/static/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

However, if I do this:

`<link href="/my_project/static/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

I do not get the error any more. So I guess it must be something in PyCharm's settings that I can fix. But what is that?

This is my `settings.py`

```
import os
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "staticfiles/")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "static"),
)
```

I also tried to set `static/` as "sources" folder.

PS: This is not a django error. It is a PyCharm error. My web application is working fine.

Comment: Have you considered using `{% static "/css/styles.css" %}`? I believe that is the right way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, I still get "Cannot Resolve Directory" error in pycharm.

Comment: Mark parent folder of `static` folder as **Resource Root**.

Comment: That is correct. Thank you. Can you make it an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 2):

I know it has been asked a while ago. I faced the same issue with Intellij with Python Plugin similar to Pycharm. 
Fix is as follows.

> Mark the template folder as Template source.

[image: Add as Template Source the Templates folder]

> Then you can add the template language as django 
>   in language and
>   frameworks <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

See the following details for reference
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this

`{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "my_app/myexample.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>`

as per docs found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

Comment: Thanks, however, this is not a django error. It is a Pycharm error. Django application still works. I modified the file but I still get the error.

Comment: Does this directory excists? `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "staticfiles/")`

Comment: Yes (`collectstatic` has been performed, too). I have tried many things actually. I think the problem lies somewhere in PyCharm settings.

Comment: have you tried to invalidate the cache? `file-> invalidate caches`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. What I've done to fix this was:

I've enabled Django support on Pycharm =  Settings -> Languages & Framework -> Django

[image: Image of my project with Django Support Enabled]